# Given two arrays, what is the most efficient way to binary overlap them?

Tags: arrays, ruby

Given:

```
a = ["thing1", "thing2", "thing3", "thing4", "thing5", "thing6"]
b = ["thing3", "thing4", "thing5"]
```

I am looking for the most efficient way to get this:

```
result #=> [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]
```

There has to be a way  better than O(n^2).

```
a.map{|v| b.include?(v) ? 1 : 0}
```

Comment: The key here is to index b (turn it into a hash, so you get O(1) lookups) before looping over A. This makes it O(N) time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
c = b.to_h{|e| [e, true]}
a.map{|e| c[e] ? 1 : 0}
```

Comment: or with active support, `c = b.index_by(&:itself)`

Comment: I've noticed you are always fond of using new methods or new  capabilities of existing methods, a good thing as it has educational value. Here, [Array#to_h](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Array.html#method-i-to_h) was permitted to have an optional block in Ruby v2.6.

Comment: Hi sawa, I have viewed your profile where you said you are going to release webserver related gem soon. May I when it would be ?

Comment: @Rajagopalan What I have under the linked page is allI gave now, and that profile is old and has not been updated. Sorry.

Comment: @sawa May I know where is the link for your web service work?

Answer (score 4):

```
require 'set'

bs = b.to_set
  #=> #<Set: {"thing3", "thing4", "thing5"}> 
a.map { |s| bs.include?(s) ? 1 : 0 }
  #=> [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]
```

Sets are implemented with a hash under the covers, so set lookups are similar to hash lookups in terms of speed of execution.